# Expresión regular para coincidir con un paréntesis literal

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo un string como este:

```
var text = 12.34 a 12.34(01-01-0001);
```

Pero tengo el siguiente problema. Al aplicarle la expresión regular :

```
var patron = new RegExp('\\d{2}\.\\d{2}\\sa\\s\\d{2}\.\\d{2}\\(\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}\\)');
```

y llamar a:

```
patron.test(texto);
```

Este retorna `false`.

He comprobado que el error me lo da por los paréntesis, es decir, si quito los paréntesis del string (variable text) y por supuesto de la expresión regular, JavaScript me lo evalúa a true. También he comprobado que si uso el patrón:

```
var patron = new RegExp('\\d{2}\.\\d{2}\\sa\\s\\d{2}\.\\d{2}\\(\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}');
```

Es decir, omito el paréntesis final en el patrón, sí me lo evalúa a true.

¿Sabe alguien por qué?

Comment: Solo por curisidad. El texto siempre sera en ese formato?

Comment: sera [esta la expresion](https://regex101.com/r/aErALH/2) el que necesitas?

Comment: tienes que escaparlo con \

Comment: No puedo reproducirlo. La primera expresión coincide, y devuelve `true`.... Pero, ¿cuál es el objetivo de ese regex? ¿Qué estás intentando hacer?

Answer (score 5):

> Este retorna false.

No es cierto. Por más que haya algunas cosas para corregir, tu expresión está coincidiendo con el texto, y `patron.test(texto)` devuelve `true`. Por lo que deberías revisar el resto de tu código. Por ejemplo, no estás usando comillas al declarar la variable `texto`.

El regex se puede expresar como:

```
var patron = /\d{2}\.\d{2} a \d{2}\.\d{2}\(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}\)/;
```

- No es necesario pasarlo como string cuando se expresa entre barras.
- `\s` coincide con un espacio en blanco (espacio, tab, enter, salto de línea o salto de página), pero para que coincida con un espacio, sólo hay que usar un espacio.

Ahora, si realmente te interesa pasarlo como un string al constructor `RegExp()`, entonces hay que escapar cada barra. Esto no es algo de regex, sino la forma en que JavaScript interpreta un string. Por ejemplo, era un error estar pasando `'\.'`, ya que Javascript le elimina la barra al interpretarlo como string, haciendo que coincida con cualquier caracter (no sólo un punto). Es decir, tu regex hubiese quedado mejor así:

```js
var patron = new RegExp('\\d{2}\\.\\d{2} a \\d{2}\\.\\d{2}\\(\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}\\)'),
    texto = '12.34 a 12.34(01-01-0001)',
    resultado;
        
resultado = patron.test(texto);
    
console.log('Resultado: ', resultado);
```

Pero realmente no hay motivo para hacerlo de esta forma. Es mucho más sencillo pasarlo sin el constructor:

```js
var patron = /\d{2}\.\d{2} a \d{2}\.\d{2}\(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}\)/,
    texto = '12.34 a 12.34(01-01-0001)',
    resultado;
        
resultado = patron.test(texto);
    
console.log('Resultado: ', resultado);
```

> omito el paréntesis final en el patrón, si me lo evalúa a true.

Porque las expresiones regulares coinciden con cualquier parte del texto, por más que sea sólo una parte en el medio del texto. Si quisieras limitarlo a que coincida sólo con el string completo, deberías especificar que coincida con:

- `^` - El inicio del texto.
- `$` - El fin del texto.

Es decir:

```
var patron = /^\d{2}\.\d{2} a \d{2}\.\d{2}\(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}\)$/;
```

Y esta expresión no va a coincidir si se omite una parte, o si el texto tiene más caracteres antes o después.

Answer (score 3):

Tienes que escapar los parentesis asi `\(` que significa que lo tome literial:

```js
var expression = /\d+\.\d+\s+\w+\s+\d+\.\d+\([\d-]+\)/;

console.log(expression.test("12.34 a 12.34(01-01-0001)"));

console.log(expression.test("12.34 a 12.34(01-00001-0000000001)"));
```